# Understanding connectHeaders when using stomp client

Tags: stomp, stompjs

I am connecting to an websocket endpoint using stompjs. One of the parameters is `connectHeaders` headers but it does not use these headers in the http request headers? Where does it use these headers?

```js
export const stompClient = new Client({
    brokerURL: "ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket",
    connectHeaders: {
        Ad: "asjfasfjldskfjsklfajsdklfasdf",
        login: "user",
        passcode: "password"
    },
    debug: function (str) {
        console.log(str);
    },
});
```

Comment: Try renaming `connectHeaders` to `headers`

Comment: `connectHeaders` looks to be the correct name as noted in the [stompjs docs](https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/Client.html#connectHeaders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those headers are used in the Stomp frame, specifically the `CONNECT` frame. Stomp frames are *modeled* on HTTP frames, but they are not synonymous. Stomp headers are distinct from HTTP headers as Stomp is not tied to HTTP. As noted in [the Stomp 1.2 specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#CONNECT_or_STOMP_Frame) for the `CONNECT` frame:

> STOMP 1.2 clients MUST set the following headers:
>
> - `accept-version` : The versions of the STOMP protocol the client supports. See [Protocol Negotiation](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Protocol_Negotiation) for more details.
> - `host` : The name of a virtual host that the client wishes to connect to. It is recommended clients set this to the host name that the socket was established against, or to any name of their choosing. If this header does not match a known virtual host, servers supporting virtual hosting MAY select a default virtual host or reject the connection.
>
> STOMP 1.2 clients MAY set the following headers:
>
> - `login` : The user identifier used to authenticate against a secured STOMP server.
> - `passcode` : The password used to authenticate against a secured STOMP server.
> - `heart-beat` : The [Heart-beating](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating) settings.